Could not establish connection to ...: The operation was aborted
The remote server can be connected in vscode but the environment can't be loaded. vscode exits with "Could not establish connection to ...: The operation was aborted."
ssh to a remote server in vscode using ProxyJump:
Host jumper
  HostName ...
  User ...
  Port ...

Host server
  HostName ...
  User ...
  ProxyJump jumper


I can use ssh to access the remote server successfully: ssh user@server -J user@jumper:port
The AllowTcpForwarding in /etc/ssh/sshd_config is set to yes.
I have killed the vscode servers on both hosts.
I have deleted the folder ~/.vscode-server.
The remote disk is not full.
Remote-SSH log:
[[16:11:24.355] Checking ssh with "C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe -V"
[16:11:24.469] > OpenSSH_for_Windows_9.5p1, LibreSSL 3.8.2

[16:11:34.149] Remote server is listening on port 44447
[16:11:34.149] Parsed server configuration: {"serverConfiguration":{"remoteListeningOn":{"port":44447},"osReleaseId":"ubuntu","arch":"x86_64","tmpDir":"/run/user/1006","platform":"linux","execServerToken":"1a11a111-a11a-111a-a1a1-a11a111a111a"},"serverStartTime":35,"installUnpackCode":""}
[16:11:34.156] Starting forwarding server. local port 51270 -> socksPort 51259 -> remotePort 44447
[16:11:34.157] Forwarding server listening on port 51270
[16:11:34.158] Waiting for ssh tunnel to be ready
[16:11:34.160] [Forwarding server port 51270] Got connection 0
[16:11:34.161] Tunneled port 44447 to local port 51270
[16:11:34.162] Resolved "ssh-remote+10.27.249.4" to "port 51270"
[16:11:34.181] Initizing new exec server for ssh-remote+10.27.249.4
[16:11:34.181] Resolving exec server at port 51270
[16:11:34.185] [Forwarding server port 51270] Got connection 1
[16:11:34.290] Exec server for ssh-remote+10.27.249.4 failed: Error: The operation was aborted
[16:11:34.293] Resolver error: Error: The operation was aborted
    at Socket.<anonymous> (c:\Users\Q\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.115.1\out\extension.js:2:293969)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:634:26)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:531:35)
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:169:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:128:3)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
[16:11:34.303] ------]([url](/))


Window log:
2024-11-18 16:11:33.964 [info] [LocalProcess0][resolveAuthority(ssh-remote,1)][11186ms] waiting...
2024-11-18 16:11:34.346 [error] [LocalProcess0][resolveAuthority(ssh-remote,1)][11568ms] returned an error {"code":"NotAvailable","message":"The operation was aborted","detail":true}
2024-11-18 16:11:34.347 [error] resolveAuthority(ssh-remote) returned an error after 11570 ms The operation was aborted
2024-11-18 16:11:34.347 [error] Error received from starting extension host (kind: Remote)
2024-11-18 16:11:34.348 [error] CodeExpectedError: The operation was aborted
    at Lot.qb (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Users/Q/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:3130:15428)
    at async Lot.pb (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Users/Q/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:3130:14794)
    at async Lot.Nb (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Users/Q/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:3136:3437)
    at async Lot.ib (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Users/Q/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:3130:12503)
2024-11-18 16:11:34.349 [error] [remote-connection][attempt 1] An error occurred in initial connection! Will retry... Error:
2024-11-18 16:11:34.350 [error] CodeExpectedError: The operation was aborted
    at Lot.qb (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Users/Q/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:3130:15428)
    at async Lot.pb (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Users/Q/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:3130:14794)
    at async Lot.Nb (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Users/Q/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:3136:3437)
    at async Lot.ib (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Users/Q/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:3130:12503)
...
2024-11-18 16:11:34.430 [error] Cannot register remote filesystem provider. Error while fetching remote environment. The operation was aborted


Extension-host log:
2024-11-18 16:11:03.868 [info] Extension host with pid 24244 started
2024-11-18 16:11:03.942 [info] ExtensionService#_doActivateExtension vscode.git-base, startup: true, activationEvent: '*', root cause: vscode.git
2024-11-18 16:11:03.963 [info] ExtensionService#_doActivateExtension vscode.git, startup: true, activationEvent: '*'
2024-11-18 16:11:04.135 [info] ExtensionService#_doActivateExtension vscode.github, startup: true, activationEvent: '*'
2024-11-18 16:11:04.638 [info] Eager extensions activated
2024-11-18 16:11:04.652 [info] ExtensionService#_doActivateExtension vscode.debug-auto-launch, startup: false, activationEvent: 'onStartupFinished'
2024-11-18 16:11:04.665 [info] ExtensionService#_doActivateExtension vscode.merge-conflict, startup: false, activationEvent: 'onStartupFinished'
2024-11-18 16:11:05.837 [info] ExtensionService#_doActivateExtension vscode.emmet, startup: false, activationEvent: 'onLanguage'
2024-11-18 16:11:14.017 [info] ExtensionService#_doActivateExtension ms-vscode.remote-explorer, startup: false, activationEvent: 'onView:remoteTargets'
2024-11-18 16:11:14.060 [info] ExtensionService#_doActivateExtension ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh, startup: false, activationEvent: 'onCommand:remote-internal.getActiveSshRemote'
2024-11-18 16:11:22.304 [info] Extension host terminating: renderer closed the MessagePort
2024-11-18 16:11:22.332 [error] Canceled: Canceled
    at new tT (file:///c:/Users/Q/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:31:108738)
    at py.U (file:///c:/Users/Q/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:31:113348)
    at s.<computed>.n.charCodeAt.s.<computed> (file:///c:/Users/Q/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:31:110842)
    at Y0.g (file:///c:/Users/Q/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:114:32313)
    at Y0.executeCommand (file:///c:/Users/Q/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:114:31817)
    at r.registerCommand.description (file:///c:/Users/Q/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:114:31147)
    at Y0.h (file:///c:/Users/Q/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:114:32833)
    at Y0.g (file:///c:/Users/Q/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:114:31910)
    at Y0.executeCommand (file:///c:/Users/Q/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:114:31817)
    at Object.executeCommand (file:///c:/Users/Q/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:156:37246)
    at t.shutdown (c:\Users\Q\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.115.1\out\extension.js:2:570757)
    at e.deactivate (c:\Users\Q\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.115.1\out\extension.js:2:842216)
    at z_.eb (file:///c:/Users/Q/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:118:11724)
    at file:///c:/Users/Q/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:118:9874
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at z_.$ (file:///c:/Users/Q/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:118:9862)
    at z_.terminate (file:///c:/Users/Q/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:118:10105)
    at EC.terminate (file:///c:/Users/Q/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:119:1424)
    at Zi (file:///c:/Users/Q/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:174:15084)
    at MessagePortMain.<anonymous> (file:///c:/Users/Q/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:174:11632)
    at MessagePortMain.emit (node:events:519:28)
    at MessagePortMain._internalPort.emit (node:electron/js2c/utility_init:2:2949) setContext undefined
2024-11-18 16:11:22.333 [info] Extension host with pid 24244 exiting with code 0
2024-11-18 16:11:24.030 [info] Extension host with pid 10732 started
2024-11-18 16:11:24.030 [info] [resolveAuthority(ssh-remote,1)][0ms] activating remote resolvers ssh-remote+10.27.249.4
2024-11-18 16:11:24.030 [info] [resolveAuthority(ssh-remote,1)][1ms] activating resolver for ssh-remote+10.27.249.4...
2024-11-18 16:11:24.043 [info] ExtensionService#_doActivateExtension ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh, startup: false, activationEvent: 'onResolveRemoteAuthority:ssh-remote'
2024-11-18 16:11:24.279 [info] [resolveAuthority(ssh-remote,1)][285ms] invoking final resolve()...
2024-11-18 16:11:25.283 [info] [resolveAuthority(ssh-remote,1)][1288ms] waiting...
2024-11-18 16:11:26.295 [info] [resolveAuthority(ssh-remote,1)][2301ms] waiting...
2024-11-18 16:11:27.307 [info] [resolveAuthority(ssh-remote,1)][3313ms] waiting...
2024-11-18 16:11:28.322 [info] [resolveAuthority(ssh-remote,1)][4328ms] waiting...
2024-11-18 16:11:29.333 [info] [resolveAuthority(ssh-remote,1)][5339ms] waiting...
2024-11-18 16:11:30.343 [info] [resolveAuthority(ssh-remote,1)][6349ms] waiting...
2024-11-18 16:11:31.354 [info] [resolveAuthority(ssh-remote,1)][7360ms] waiting...
2024-11-18 16:11:32.367 [info] [resolveAuthority(ssh-remote,1)][8373ms] waiting...
2024-11-18 16:11:33.376 [info] [resolveAuthority(ssh-remote,1)][9382ms] waiting...
2024-11-18 16:11:34.307 [error] [resolveAuthority(ssh-remote,1)][10309ms] returned an error The operation was aborted
2024-11-18 16:11:34.395 [info] Eager extensions activated
2024-11-18 16:11:34.565 [info] ExtensionService#_doActivateExtension ms-vscode.remote-explorer, startup: false, activationEvent: 'onCommand:remote-explorer.refresh'


Shared log:
2024-11-18 16:11:08.523 [error] [network] #1: https://az764295.vo.msecnd.net/extensions/marketplace.json - error GET net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED 
It seems that the error in the shared log is not related to SSH, because it pops up even if the server is not connected.
Extension version: 0.115.1
VS Code version: Code 1.95.3 (f1a4fb101478ce6ec82fe9627c43efbf9e98c813, 2024-11-13T14:50:04.152Z)
OS version: Windows_NT x64 10.0.19045
